# htaccess - regex - question mark in address

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have to import articles from Joomla to another website and have a problem:

The code is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/article\/(.+)\/(.+)\.html$ index.php?content=article&id=$2&alias=$3 [L]
```

The problem occurs when alias contains question mark. How to avoid 404 in that and another "special-chars" cases?
I guess I should use `{QUERY_STRING}` but don't know how in that case.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the alias link?

Comment: Do you mean `http://example.com/foo/article/123/bar.html?name=value` or `http://example.com/foo/article/123/baz?.html`?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your regular expression. I hope that i have understood your challenge correctly. I have also provided a permalink to my test. Both of the URLs you provided in the comments passed.

RewriteRule ^(.+)/article/(.+)/(.+).html(.*)$ index.php?content=article&id=$2&alias=$3 [L]

[Here is a link to my regular expression test.](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5E%28.%2b%29%5C/article%5C/%28.%2b%29%5C/%28.%2b%29%5C.html%28.%2a%29%24&input=http://example.com/foo/article/123/baz?.html%22Here%20is%20a%20link%20to%20my%20test%20on%20regexpal.com.%22)

Comment: Thanks, but its not my problem. This example will help you to understand it: I need to rewrite /article/6172/foo1?foo2.html. When i try to do it foo2 is seen as request. i want to avoid that